# How to implement a look up table for a range of values of two columns

Tags: .net, sql-server, database, winforms, visual-studio-2010

**Edit:** updated the two tables to sync with each other. These are the only tables involved. simply put, i need to take a count of all the unique records and display it in a 2d format.

I have a table of optical lenses, a sample of which follows:

```
            Spherical|Cylindrical
            ---------------------
             0       |    0.5
             0.25    |    0.75
             0.25    |    0.5
             0       |    0
             0       |    0.25
             0       |    0.5
             0.25    |    0.75
             0.25    |    0.5
             0.5     |    0
             0.75    |    0
             0.75    |    0
             0.5     |    0.25
             0.5     |    0.75
             0.75    |    0.25
             0.5     |    0.75
             0.75    |    0.75
             0.75    |    0.5
             0.75    |    0.5
```

and so on...

I want to display a bird's eye view of the count of lenses in each combination in a 2d format this way:

```
Spherical/Cylindrical|0|0.25|0.5|0.75|... upto 8 in steps of 0.25
-----------------------------------------     
                 0   |1|  1 | 2 | 1  |
               0.25  |0|  0 | 2 | 2  |
               0.5   |1|  2 | 0 | 2  |
               0.75  |2|  1 | 2 | 1  |
                ...
               upto 30 in steps of 0.25
```

How do I implement this in c#.net with sql server 2008? which would be the best approach?

I have a couple of thoughts:

1. Generate a view at run time using some special query and format it
   in 2d
2. Create a 2d table kind of (in the above format) and update the
   count each time the lens table is updated.

Please give me your thoughts and advise on this. Thanks!

Comment: I would definitely go for 1 (having to update the data constantly means it is always going to be out of date unless you use triggers, which are going to suck). But I am having a hard time understanding where the data actually comes from. Can you show sample data, and how the counts have been derived?

Comment: I'm assuming there's another table you've left out right? One that's holding the lens count for each of these.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I've updated the two tables to sync with each other. Please have a look. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is a sample query for how to make a view:

```
--build table variable and sample data
DECLARE @Optical table (Spherical numeric(4,2),Cylindrical numeric(4,2))
INSERT INTO @Optical VALUES (   0, 0.5)
INSERT INTO @Optical VALUES (0.25,0.75)
INSERT INTO @Optical VALUES (1.25, 0.5)
INSERT INTO @Optical VALUES (1.25, 0.5)
INSERT INTO @Optical VALUES (   0,  0)

--query to use as a basis for the view
;with AllSpherical AS --this recursive CTE builds the 121 rows for: 0.00 to 30.0
(
    SELECT convert(numeric(4,2),0.0) AS Spherical
    UNION ALL
    SELECT convert(numeric(4,2),Spherical+0.25)
        FROM AllSpherical
    WHERE Spherical<=29.75
)
SELECT 
    s.Spherical 
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN o.Cylindrical=0.00 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c_000
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN o.Cylindrical=0.25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c_025
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN o.Cylindrical=0.50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c_050
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN o.Cylindrical=0.75 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c_075
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN o.Cylindrical=1.00 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c_100
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN o.Cylindrical=1.25 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c_125
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN o.Cylindrical=1.50 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c_150
        ,SUM(CASE WHEN o.Cylindrical=1.75 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS c_175
        --... add a case for all columns

    FROM AllSpherical              s
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @Optical   o ON s.Spherical=o.Spherical
    GROUP BY s.Spherical 
    OPTION (MAXRECURSION 120)
```

output:

```
Spherical  c_000 c_025 c_050 c_075 c_100 c_125 c_150 c_175
---------- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- ----- -----
0.00       1     0     1     0     0     0     0     0
0.25       0     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
0.50       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
0.75       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
1.00       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
1.25       0     0     2     0     0     0     0     0
1.50       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
1.75       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2.00       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2.25       0     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
...

(121 row(s) affected)
```

you can build a traditional view using this query if you update the raw data much more than you would read this view. this would be your option 1

if you plan on reading this view much more than you update the raw data consider persisting the view: [Improving Performance with SQL Server 2005 Indexed Views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917715.aspx)  and [Creating Indexed Views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx).  This basically materializes the view and when you insert/update/delete the underlying table, the view's stored data is updated much like an automatic system level trigger would to keep them in sync.  this would be your option 2, but the system would do all the "hard" work of keeping everything in sync.

Comment: Thanks a million! Looks like this is what I need. I need to display this view as the default page, so i guess I should be going with option 2. I'm a complete newbie to .net and sqls.. (i'm from mainframes/cobol trying my hand in other 'real' programming languages).. I'll try this out and update you. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I tried this out, and it's working perfectly! Thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

Borrowing from KM's table variable, here is another way to do it that uses `PIVOT` and avoids 33 `SUM(CASE...)` expressions.

```
DECLARE @Optical TABLE (Spherical DECIMAL(4,2), Cylindrical DECIMAL(4,2));

INSERT INTO @Optical VALUES (   0, 0.5);
INSERT INTO @Optical VALUES (0.25, 0.75);
INSERT INTO @Optical VALUES (1.25, 0.5);
INSERT INTO @Optical VALUES (1.25, 0.5);
INSERT INTO @Optical VALUES (   0, 0);

;WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT TOP (33) [row] = (ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])-1)*0.25
        FROM sys.objects ORDER BY [row]
), y AS
(
    SELECT Spherical = x.[row], o.Cylindrical
        FROM x 
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @Optical AS o
        ON x.[row] = o.Spherical
)
SELECT pvt.* FROM y 
PIVOT (COUNT(y.Cylindrical) FOR y.Cylindrical IN 
(
  [0.00],[0.25],[0.50],[0.75],[1.00],[1.25],[1.50],[1.75],[2.00],[2.25],[2.50],[2.75],
  [3.00],[3.25],[3.50],[3.75],[4.00],[4.25],[4.50],[4.75],[5.00],[5.25],[5.50],[5.75],
  [6.00],[6.25],[6.50],[6.75],[7.00],[7.25],[7.50],[7.75],[8.00]
)) AS pvt
ORDER BY pvt.Spherical;
```

Now, you're probably thinking, I don't want to type out all those values in the `PIVOT` section, but you can generate those pretty quickly:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)= N'';

;WITH x AS 
(
    SELECT TOP (33) [row] = (ROW_NUMBER() 
        OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])-1)*0.25
        FROM sys.objects ORDER BY [row]
)
SELECT @sql = @sql + ',[' + RTRIM(CONVERT(DECIMAL(4,2), [row])) + ']' FROM x;

SET @sql = STUFF(@sql, 1, 1, '');

PRINT @sql;
```

Comment: Definitely +1, for the dynamic SQL.

Comment: OP only wants 33 columns `up to 8 in steps of 0.25`, which is substantially fewer than your statement: `avoids 121 SUM(CASE...) expressions.`

Comment: Whoops, I thought it was 30 on both sides.

Comment: This one works perfect too! Thank you so much! Is there any way in SO to accept two answers?